# Javascript modules circular dependency of a class and a function

Tags: javascript, module

// c.js

```
import { F1 } from "./main.js"

export class C { }

export function F2() {
    F1(); // Deleting this line causes C below to become properly defined
}
```

// main.js

```
import { C } from "./c.js"

export function F1() {
}

let c = new C(); // C is undefined here
```

// index.htm

```
    <script src="c.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Here's a snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-kirch-sn3smr in codesandbox showing the error.

Why is it that `C` is undefined? What exactly does import do if not make sure `C` is defined? `c.js` is before `main.js` in my index.htm file, shouldn't `c.js` have run first, therefore defining `C`, then `main.js` uses `c`, and everything is OK? Why does deleting `F1()` matter? I never even actually call `F2()`!

Comment: "*Deleting this line causes C below to become properly defined*" - no (unless you use a bundler or something that removes unused imports). Removing the `import { F1 } from "./main.js"` line can make a difference, removing the call `F1()` should not.

Comment: "*c.js is before main.js in my index.htm file, shouldn't c.js have run first?*" - no, the order in the html file does not really matter. What matters is that *c.js* imports *main.js*, so the dependency evaluates before the module itself - and in a circular dependency the entry point matters. Try removing `<script src="c.js" type="module"></script>` (but only load *main.js* with its dependency on *c.js*) and it should work as well.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this circular dependency issue, you can refactor your code which avoid this situation altogether. One possible solution is to move the F1 function to a separate module that doesn't depend on C, and then both c.js and main.js can import from that new module without circular dependencies.

```
// c.js
import { F1 } from "./utility_module.js";

export class C {}

export function F2() {
  F1();
}

// main.js
import { C } from "./c.js";
import { F1 } from "./utility_module.js";

let c = new C();

// utility_module.js
export function F1() {}

// index.html
<script src="utility_module.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="c.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: I know I can do that. The question is why does it work this way?

Comment: imports are handled in two phase, i,e declaration, and execution. in first nothing gets executed, while in second these gets executed in order of import. during the first phase, C is not yet defined when main.js tries to import it from c.js. This is because execution did n't reached point where C is defined in c.js. that's why C is undefined in main.js.  When you add the line F1() in F2() in c.js, it triggers the execution of F1 from main.js. This causes the code execution to reach the point where C is defined in c.js, and hence C becomes properly defined in main.js.